Create a relative path shortcut with the SLDF_HAS_RELPATH flag in c++
After doing some research on how to create a shortcut with a relative path target—most answers online suggest using %COMSPEC% /c start .\something.exe—I've stumbled across this question from 2010. One of the answers suggests that relative path shortcuts are actually supported by Windows without having to use some workaround. For that, you have to write the shortcut's binary, shortcuts having a SLDF_HAS_RELPATH flag.
I tried to port the original answer's NSIS script into C++:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj_core.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <combaseapi.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

// Helper function to write hexadecimal bytes to a file.
void FileWriteHexBytes(std::ofstream &file, const std::string &hexBytes) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < hexBytes.length(); i += 2) {
        std::string byteString = hexBytes.substr(i, 2);
        unsigned char byte = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::stoi(byteString, nullptr, 16));
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&byte), 1);
    }
}

// Function to create a relative symbolic link file.
void CreateRelativeLnk(const std::string &filePath, const std::string &relativeTargetPath) {
    std::ofstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << filePath << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Header and flags.
    FileWriteHexBytes(file, "4C0000000114020000000000C000000000000046");
    FileWriteHexBytes(file, "48010400");  // Flags
    FileWriteHexBytes(file, "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000");

    // Write the length of the relative target path (must be less than 255).
    unsigned char pathLength = static_cast<unsigned char>(relativeTargetPath.length());
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&pathLength), 1);
    file.put('\0');  // Null terminator

    // Write the relative target path.
    file.write(relativeTargetPath.c_str(), relativeTargetPath.length());

    // Optionally, handle icon (not implemented here).
    // Fake default .exe icon.
    FileWriteHexBytes(file, "05003e2e657865");

    file.close();
}

// Function to retrieve and display the target path of a shortcut (.lnk) file using COM.
void GetShortcutTarget(const std::string &shortcutPath) {
    // Initialize COM library.
    HRESULT hres = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize COM library." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Create an IShellLink object.
    CComPtr<IShellLink> psl;
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (void**)&psl);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create IShellLink instance." << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }

    // Query for the IPersistFile interface for loading the shortcut file.
    CComPtr<IPersistFile> ppf;
    hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&ppf);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get IPersistFile interface." << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }

    // Load the shortcut file.
    std::wstring wideShortcutPath(shortcutPath.begin(), shortcutPath.end());
    hres = ppf->Load(wideShortcutPath.c_str(), STGM_READ);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load the shortcut file: " << shortcutPath << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }

    // Get the target path from the shortcut.
    char targetPath[MAX_PATH];
    hres = psl->GetPath(targetPath, MAX_PATH, NULL, 0);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
        std::cout << "Target path of shortcut: " << targetPath << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get target path." << std::endl;
    }

    // Uninitialize COM library.
    CoUninitialize();
}

int main() {
    // Example usage of CreateRelativeLnk function.
    std::string outputFile = "example.lnk";
    std::string relativePath = "..\\target\\application.exe";
    CreateRelativeLnk(outputFile, relativePath);

    std::cout << "Link file created: " << outputFile << std::endl;

    // Example usage of GetShortcutTarget function.
    GetShortcutTarget(outputFile);

    return 0;
}

While the code itself is valid and is able to be compiled successfully, the shortcut created does not work, and its property tag suggests it somehow doesn't have a target:

And the program does not find a target either:
Link file created: [...]\example.lnk
Target path of shortcut:
However, by looking at the binary, it seems that the target path is there:

For anyone wondering, I did make sure that .\target\application.exe existed.

Why try to write binary format manually when you can use the API to create the shortcut and set the flags?

I suggest you could refer to the Blog: How do I create a shortcut whose target is specified by a relative path?

@Luke I will consider an API solution, but I would still like to know what's wrong with the binary

@Jeaninez-MSFT Thank you! It works perfectly. The only oddity with this approach is that it sets an absolute path, but it's "fake" since moving the shortcut and the executable together doesn't break the shortcut. Is there a way to set a "fake" relative path as the target for convenience? Or anything else, like a word for example. Since the trick do not rely on the target

I don't know what's wrong with the binary data. You can peruse the documentation at your leisure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/16cb4ca1-9339-4d0c-a68d-bf1d6cc0f943
